# How to make a future that gets completed when any of the given CompletableFutures is completed with a result that matches a certain predicate?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a list of `CompletableFuture<MyService>`:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyService>>
```

where `MyService` is immutable like the following:

```
public class MyService {
    public boolean isAvailable() {
         return true; // or false
    }
}
```

I now want a future that is completed when one of the futures:

- is completed; **and**
- for the `MyService` instance as provided by that future: `MyService.isAvailable()` returns `true`

When proceeding, I need to have the `MyService` instance that is available. In other words, I want a `CompletableFuture<MyService>` which completes when the two conditions are met.

How can I do this? I know I can use `CompletableFuture.anyOf(...)` to proceeed when one of the futures completes, but I am unsure how to integrate the second requirement: `MyService.isAvailable()` must be true.

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed"? What do you want to do? What's the problem with calling `MyService.isAvailable()`? Do you want to wait for it to become true? Also your question title does not mean much due to its grammar.

Comment: I want a `CompletableFuture` which completes when the 2 conditions are met.

Comment: Your service needs to provide a future that completes when it is available then. Otherwise the only way to do this is to poll the service at regular intervals to check whether it is available…

Comment: @DidierL I am not sure about that. Note that `MyService.isAvailable()` returns `true` or `false` depending on internal members, so no asynchronous checks or anything else is done. I need some kind of chaining `CompletableFuture`, as you can do with `filter()` on streams.

Comment: So in the end was any of the proposed answers helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Update: I think I understood your problem now. Would it help you to proxy your futures like this?

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyService>> givenFutures; // wherever they came from

CompletableFuture<MyService>[] myFutures = givenFutures.stream()
        .map(future -> {
            final CompletableFuture<MyService> futureWithCheck = new CompletableFuture<>();

            future.thenAccept(myService -> {
                if (myService.isAvailable()) {
                    futureWithCheck.complete(myService);
                }
            });

            return futureWithCheck;})
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

// blocking
MyService availableService = (MyService) CompletableFuture.anyOf(myFutures).get();

// do what you want to do with the available service
```

---

Update 2: I thought about your question regarding `thenCompose` and perhaps the middle part of my solution could be expressed like this:

```
CompletableFuture<MyService>[] myFutures = givenFutures.stream()
        .map(future ->
                future.thenCompose(myService ->
                        myService.isAvailable() ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(myService) : new CompletableFuture<>()))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

---

Old Answer, for completeness:

(was gonna comment but I have too little reputation)

Looks like you will either have to poll `MyService.isAvailable()` repeatedly and complete another `CompletableFuture` once this returns true or `MyService` will (like Didier L commented) have to return a Future which it keeps track of and completes, once the internal members you mentioned are changed. So for example the setter for each member involved will have to check whether `isAvailable()` is true and if so, complete all futures that it handed out before.

In both cases you have to chain the additional `Future` with the ones you have. Guavas `Futures` has useful methods, but probably `CompletableFuture.allOf(…)` will do the job.

Comment: If it can't ever change, what would you be waiting for (once your other `Futures` complete)? It would mean that you would either wait forever or proceed immediately. In both cases a future is not needed but a simple call to `isAvailable()` after your other `Futures` complete does the trick. Or would you wait for the instance of `MyService` to be replaced by one where `isAvailable()` is true? Then the place where this instance is set is where you have to hook in your last `Future`.

Comment: No, I don't think so. `CompletableFuture.anyOf(...)` completes when one of the `CompletableFuture<MyService>`. Then it stops waiting. But this particular `MyService` might return false for `isAvailable()`. So I need to continue waiting as long as I have no `MyService` instance for which `isAvailable()` returns `true`.

Comment: a) i think you are mixing up concurrency with other matters here and b) there is `CompletableFuture.anyOf(…)` and `CompletableFuture.allOf(…)`

Comment: Calling `anyOf(...)` will not help, as this might provide a `MyService` for which `isAvailable()` returns `false`. Calling `allOf(...)` is overkill, as now I am waiting for **all** services. I want to proceed from the moment there is one service for which `isAvailable()` return `true`.

Comment: That's a clever solution. I will try it out and report back!

Comment: not sure though if you might have to use `thenAcceptAsync` - maybe worth trying if the solution above doesn't work

Comment: Nice solution – I was also thinking about something similar. Note that `Stream` has a [`toArray()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

Comment: Could we also convert the original futures with `thenCompose(...)`? Something like `futures.stream().map(future -> future.thenCompose(...)).toArray()`. In the body, we can check for `isAvailable()` on the service and return an already completed `CompletableFuture` with that service if that is the case.

Comment: Looks promising. Let me know if it works and I’ll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: `thenCompose()` is only executed _after_ the future is completed, so that would be basically the same as `allOf()`.

Comment: Right, I forgot that. I'm off for today, I will pick up the work tomorrow. Thank you for your ideas @Ole and @DidierL!

Comment: I had the same problem and this helped. I had no idea you could simply create an empty future and it will run forever until you manually `complete()` it. This is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following service, where the future gets completed only if the service is available:

```
public static class MyService {
    private String name;

    public MyService(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<MyService> isAvailable() {
        CompletableFuture<MyService> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
            boolean available = checkAvailability();
            if (available)
                future.complete(this);
        });
        return future;
    }

    private boolean checkAvailability() {
        try {
            int ms = new Random().nextInt(1000);
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return new Random().nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

And then use the service like this:

```
MyService s1 = new MyService("one");
MyService s2 = new MyService("two");
CompletableFuture<MyService> f1 = s1.isAvailable();
CompletableFuture<MyService> f2 = s2.isAvailable();

System.out.println("waiting for the first service to be available...");
CompletableFuture<Object> any = CompletableFuture.anyOf(f1, f2);
System.out.println("and the winner is: " + any.get());

// you can now safely cancel all futures
f1.cancel(true);
f2.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Please read my other comments, this is not what I really want. I have a `List<CompletableFuture<MyService>>` and I cannot change the source of `MyService`. I need to wait for a `MyService` instance to become available **and** for which `isAvailable()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a `CompletableFuture` can only be completed once, you can create one that will be completed by the first future that returns an available service:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyService>> myServiceFutures = …

final CompletableFuture<MyService> availableMyServiceFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
myServiceFutures.forEach(future -> future.thenAccept(myService -> {
    if (myService.isAvailable()) {
        // call will be ignored if already completed
        availableMyServiceFuture.complete(myService);
    }
}));
```

Additionally, you may want this future to complete exceptionally if no service is available:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(myServiceFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[myServiceFutures.size()]))
        .whenComplete((e, r) -> {
            // TODO handle failure of individual futures if that can happen
            if (myServiceFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).noneMatch(MyService::isAvailable)) {
                availableMyServiceFuture.completeExceptionally(new IllegalStateException("No service is available"));
            }
        });
```