# How to stop parallel stream once findAny match found?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future

I'm trying locate the first (any) member of a list that matches a given predicate like so:

```java
Item item = items.parallelStream()
  .map(i -> i.doSomethingExpensive())
  .filter(predicate)
  .findAny()
  .orElse(null);
```

I would expect that once `findAny()` gets a match, it would return immediately, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Instead it seems to wait for the map method to finish on most of the elements before returning. How can I return the first result immediately and cancel the other parallel streams? Is there a better way to do this than using streams such as `CompletableFuture`?

Here's a simple example to show the behavior:

```java
private static void log(String msg) {
    private static void log(String msg) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg);
}

Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
Optional<Integer> num = nums.parallelStream()
  .map(n -> {
    long delay = Math.abs(random.nextLong()) % 10000;
    log("Waiting on " + n + " for " + delay + " ms");
    try { Thread.sleep(delay); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { System.err.println("Interruption error"); }
    return n * n;
  })
  .filter(n -> n < 30)
  .peek(n -> log("Found match: " + n))
  .findAny();

log("First match: " + num);
```

Log output:

```
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 9 for 2271 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 2 for 1124 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 13 for 547 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 4 for 517 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 1 for 1210 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 6 for 2646 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 0 for 4393 ms
14:52:27.061 Waiting on 12 for 5520 ms
14:52:27.581 Found match: 16
14:52:27.582 Waiting on 3 for 5365 ms
14:52:28.188 Found match: 4
14:52:28.275 Found match: 1
14:52:31.457 Found match: 0
14:52:32.950 Found match: 9
14:52:32.951 First match: Optional[0]
```

Once a match is found (in this case 16), `findAny()` does not return immediately, but instead blocks until the remaining threads finish. In this case, the caller is waiting an extra 5 seconds before returning after a match has already been found.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading `findAny` mostly runs in parallel. That could be the cause of what you are observing probably.

Comment: I'm wondering if that might be it. From the logs, it looks like not all the values are being processed (which is good), but the ones that are need to finish processing before the result is returned (not so good).

Comment: I got it, I read it in the differences between `findFirst` and `findAny` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359112/difference-between-findany-and-findfirst-in-java-8 ... but haven't analysed your question honestly to the details of which one amongst them is your requirement.

Comment: My expectation is that it does the best it can, so to speak: it attempts to cancel the other threads, but they don't necessarily notice the cancellation while they're trying to evaluate the map function.  That's about as good as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead it seems to wait for the map method to finish on most of the elements before returning.

This is not correct.

When speaking of the elements which are already being processed, it will wait for the completion of *all of them*, as the Stream API allows concurrent processing of data structures which are not intrinsically thread safe. It must ensure that all potential concurrent access has been finished before returning from the terminal operation.

When talking about the entire stream, it’s simply not fair to test a stream of only 14 elements on an 8 core machine. Of course, there will be at least 8 concurrent operations started, that’s what it is all about. You are adding fuel to the flames by using `findFirst()` instead of `findAny()`, as that doesn’t mean returning the first found element in processing order, but the first element in encounter order, i.e. exactly zero in your example, so threads processing other chunks than the first can’t assume that their result is the correct answer and are even more willing to help processing other candidates than with `findAny()`.

When you use

```
List<Integer> nums = IntStream.range(0, 200).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Optional<Integer> num = nums.parallelStream()
        .map(n -> {
            long delay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10_000);
            log("Waiting on " + n + " for " + delay + " ms");
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(delay));
            return n * n;
        })
        .filter(n -> n < 40_000)
        .peek(n -> log("Found match: " + n))
        .findAny();

log("First match: " + num);
```

You will get a similar number of tasks running to completion, despite the far bigger number of stream elements.

Note that `CompletableFuture` also doesn’t support interruption, so the only builtin feature for returning any result and canceling the other jobs, that comes into my mind, is the old `ExecutorService.invokeAny`.

To built the feature of mapping and filtering for it, we can use the following helper function:

```
static <T,R> Callable<R> mapAndfilter(T t, Function<T,R> f, Predicate<? super R> p) {
    return () -> {
        R r = f.apply(t);
        if(!p.test(r)) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return r;
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, there’s only the option of completing with a value or exceptionally, therefore we have to use an exception for non-matching elements.

Then we can use it like

```
ExecutorService es = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
Integer result = es.invokeAny(IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> mapAndfilter(i,
        n -> {
            long delay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10_000);
            log("Waiting on " + n + " for " + delay + " ms");
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(delay));
            return n * n;
        },
        n -> n < 10_000))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

log("result: "+result);
```

and it will not only cancel the pending tasks, it will return without waiting for them to finish.

Of course, this implies that the source data, the jobs operating upon, must be either immutable or thread safe.

Comment: Thanks. Your first paragraph explains what I was seeing a lot better than I could describe it. Using `invokeAny` with an `ExecutorService` seems to be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to illustrate how parallelStream works:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third", "4th", "5th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th");

    String result = list.parallelStream()
                        .map(s -> {
                            System.out.println("map: " + s);
                            return s;
                        })
                        .filter(s -> {
                            System.out.println("fiter: " + s);
                            return s.equals("8th");
                        })
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);

    System.out.println("result=" + result);
```

There are two options to achieve what you're looking for, to stop expensive operation with a filter:

1. Don't use streams at all, use a simple for or enhanced for
2. Filter first, then map with the expensive operation

Comment: If I use a for statement, then I lose the concurrence, which is important in the case of multiple concurrent operations. If 2 operations take 5 seconds to complete, I'd prefer not to wait for the first one to complete just to find out it wasn't what I was looking for. As for filtering first, I think that will only work if I want to filter on the value before the map. I need to filter on the result of the map.

Comment: You can do some tests with the code I put above. There's not way to stop parallel stream, and even if it would it won't be safe since you won't be sure to get the results you expect. So probably you'll need to choose between parallel or stop when something is found

Answer (score 1):

There are several things at play here. The first thing is that `parallelStream()` uses the common `ForkJoinPool` by default, which makes the calling thread participate as well. This means that if one of the slow tasks is currently running on the calling thread, it has to finish before the caller gets the control back.

You can see this by modifying the code a little bit to log the thread names, and log when finished the wating:

```
private static void log(String msg) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + " [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + " " + msg);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
    Optional<Integer> num = nums.parallelStream()
            .map(n -> {
                long delay = Math.abs(random.nextLong()) % 10000;
                log("Waiting on " + n + " for " + delay + " ms");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println("Interruption error");
                }
                log("finished waiting");
                return n * n;
            })
            .filter(n -> n < 30)
            .peek(n -> log("Found match: " + n))
            .findAny();

    log("First match: " + num);
}
```

Sample output:

```
13:56:52.954 [main]  Waiting on 9 for 9936 ms
13:56:52.956 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  Waiting on 4 for 7436 ms
13:56:52.970 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  Waiting on 1 for 6523 ms
13:56:52.983 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  Waiting on 6 for 7488 ms
13:56:59.494 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  finished waiting
13:56:59.496 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  Found match: 1
13:57:00.392 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  finished waiting
13:57:00.392 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  Found match: 16
13:57:00.471 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  finished waiting
13:57:02.892 [main]  finished waiting
13:57:02.894 [main]  First match: Optional[1]
```

Here as you can see, 2 matches are found but the main thread is still busy, so it cannot return the match now.

This does not always explain all cases though:

```
13:58:52.116 [main]  Waiting on 9 for 5256 ms
13:58:52.143 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  Waiting on 4 for 4220 ms
13:58:52.148 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  Waiting on 1 for 2136 ms
13:58:52.158 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  Waiting on 6 for 7262 ms
13:58:54.294 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  finished waiting
13:58:54.295 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  Found match: 1
13:58:56.364 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  finished waiting
13:58:56.364 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  Found match: 16
13:58:57.399 [main]  finished waiting
13:58:59.422 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  finished waiting
13:58:59.424 [main]  First match: Optional[1]
```

This might be explained by the way the fork-join pool merges the results. It seems some improvements are possible.

As an alternative, you could indeed do this using `CompletableFuture`:

```
// you should probably also pass your own executor to supplyAsync()
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = nums.stream().map(n -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    long delay = Math.abs(random.nextLong()) % 10000;
    log("Waiting on " + n + " for " + delay + " ms");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Interruption error");
    }
    log("finished waiting");
    return n * n;
})).collect(Collectors.toList());
CompletableFuture<Integer> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
        .thenApply(unused -> futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).filter(n -> n < 30).findAny().orElse(null));
// shortcircuiting
futures.forEach(f -> f.thenAccept(r -> {
    if (r < 30) {
        log("Found match: " + r);
        result.complete(r);
    }
}));
// cancelling remaining tasks
result.whenComplete((r, t) -> futures.forEach(f -> f.cancel(true)));

log("First match: " + result.join());
```

Output:

```
14:57:39.815 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]  Waiting on 0 for 7964 ms
14:57:39.815 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  Waiting on 2 for 5743 ms
14:57:39.817 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2]  Waiting on 1 for 9179 ms
14:57:45.562 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  finished waiting
14:57:45.563 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  Found match: 4
14:57:45.564 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]  Waiting on 3 for 7320 ms
14:57:45.566 [main]  First match: 4
```

Note that the `cancel(true)` does not actually cancel the ongoing tasks (no interruption will occur for example), but it prevents further tasks from being run (you can even see that it might not be immediate since worker 3 still started to execute the next one).

You should also use your own executor, with the appropriate size based on whether it is more CPU or I/O intensive. As you can see, the default uses the common pool and thus it does not use all cores.

The `allOf()` is mainly needed in case no match is found. If you can guarantee that there is at least one match, you could simply use a `new CompletableFuture() instead.

Finally, as a simple approach I repeated the `filter` check, but it's easy to move that logic inside the main logic, return `null` or a marker, and then test for that in both places.

See also [How to make a future that gets completed when any of the given CompletableFutures is completed with a result that matches a certain predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445121/how-to-make-a-future-that-gets-completed-when-any-of-the-given-completablefuture)